# SSH unable to access interactive shell

Tags: ssh

Iam trying to ssh from macOS into Kali Linux. Both devices are on the same subnet, connected by a home router.

I initiated the ssh service on the device running Kali and set up ***/etc/ssh/sshd_config*** to use a password on login. (*I set PasswordAuthentication yes and  ChrootDirectory /home/remote in /etc/ssh/sshd_config*)

Running the following command on the Mac ***ssh user@192.168.xxx.xxx*** logs me in and disconnects after issuing the following error ***/bin/bash No such file or directory***

I can confirm that ***/bin/bash*** does exist’s and is listed in ***/etc/shells***.

Error logs from ***/var/log/auth.log*** points to this
error ***/dev/pts/zsh No Such file or directory***

I have been told this might be a install issue, I have already tried reinstalling, It doesn’t work.

Can someone help me figure this out.

Comment: If you log in directly to the Kali device and run `/bin/bash` do you get an error or a shell? If you log into the Kali device and run `su - user` and give the password do you get an error or a shell? Please show the exact error messages. My first **guess** is that this is a line ending issue.

Comment: You "_set up /etc/ssh/sshd_config to use a password on login_". What exactly did you do?

Comment: @icarus no I do not get error for both the cases

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yes I get the same error for ssh user@127.0.0.1

Comment: @roaima I set `PasswordAuthentication yes` and  `ChrootDirectory /home/remote` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: That's vital information and explains the reason for the problem. Please add it to your question

Comment: Is there a /home/remote/bin/bash file on the Kali system? Is there a /home/remote/dev/pts directory? Which guide were you following which told you to set up the ChrootDirectory?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @icarus, yes the issue was with the `ChrootDirectory` setting in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Commenting out `ChrootDirectory /home/remote` worked.
I worked out the cause for this issue from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/542440/how-does-chrootdirectory-and-a-users-home-directory-work-together) question. Thank you everyone, I can't believe I missed something this silly.