# How to make chrooted SFTP home writable and default to "~"path

Tags: debian, ssh, sftp, chroot

My current SFTP chroot setup is like this:
User `example` is chrooted in directory `/home/example/chroot/`. He is unable to go up in directory tree (his unescapable root is `/home/example`).

How to make user's root `/home/example/chroot` and also make it default to `~`? As for now, some programs are unable to create temporary files, because they think that user's home is `/home/example` which is not writable (it is owned by root, so chroot can work properly).

My `sshd_config`:

```
# Chroot
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match Group sftp_only
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        ChrootDirectory %h
        ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /chroot
```

Is it even possible? I am using Debian 10.

Comment: Are these "some programs" operating locally on the SFTP server system, or do they run somewhere else and connect to this system with SFTP? If they are running locally, have you done `usermod -d /home/example/chroot example` or similar, or does the local user database still say the user's home is `/home/example`? (check with `getent passwd example | cut -d : -f 6`)

Comment: See also [my answer to another SSHD ChrootDirectory question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/542507/258991) for two versions of a symlink trick you might need to do in some situations.

Comment: Oops, if you do a `usermod -d /home/example/chroot example`, then you'll probably need to change the `ChrootDirectory` configuration line to `ChrootDirectory /home/%u`.